# Remove tabs only from within double-quoted strings in TSV file?

Tags: bash, text-processing

I have a TSV file that that upon further inspection sometimes contains tabs within *some* of the double-quoted string fields for some rows (seems to happen arbitrarily among various string fields) and would like to remove these in bash. Eg. when looking at the file with `:set list` in `vi` I see something like...

```sh
1234^I"some^Itext field"^I"more text"^I4678^I"other^Itext here"$
```

and would like to get something like...

```sh
1234^I"some text field"^I"more text"^I4678^I"other text here"$
```

Anyone know how this can be done efficiently in bash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have GNU awk, you can use its `FPAT` variable to split each line into fields, then use `gsub` to edit them:

```
gawk -v OFS='\t' -v FPAT='"(""|[^"]*)*"|[^\t]*' '
    {
        for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)
            gsub(/\t/, " ", $i)
        print
    }
' in.tsv > out.tsv
```

`OFS` is set to be tab so that `print` produces tab-separated output.

The value of FPAT I have given here defines fields to be:

- double-quote
- followed by any number of:

  - two double-quotes
  - or any number of characters that are not double-quotes
- followed by double-quote

or:

- any number of characters that are not tabs

Note that gawk can't handle embedded newlines in fields.

See: https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Splitting-By-Content.html

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the most robust solution, but maybe you can use it as a jumping off point.

```sh
sed -e 's/\("[^\t"]*\)\t\([^\t"]*\)"/\1 \2/g' tsv_file.txt
```

I think a proper solution would require a small text parser which would probably be better written in a language like Perl or Python.